# ReactJS - nested component props are null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to nest some components in ReactJS in order to buid a todo app, however when the element is passed into the map function it is undefined.

The nesting component:

```
var El2= class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) { //constructor
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          todos: ['work out', 'eat breakfast', 'take a shower']/*,
        }
      }

    /**********methods**********/

    onDelete(item){
      let updatedTodos = this.state.todos.filter(function(val,index){
        return item!==val;
      });
      this.setState({todos:updatedTodos});
    }

    /********rendering method*******/

    render(){
      let todos = this.state.todos;
      todos=todos.map((item,index)=>{
        return(
          <TodoItem item={item} key={index} onDelete={this.onDelete}/>
        )
      })


        return(//works kinda like a main function
            <div id="todo-list"> 
                <p>the busiest people have the most leisure...</p>
                <ul>{todos}</ul>
            </div>
            );


    }//component rendering
}
```

The nested component:

```
//Creating TodoItem component

var TodoItem = class App extends React.Component{

  DeleteItem(){
    console.log(this); //trying to log the item outputs undefined
    this.props.onDelete(this.props.item);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <li>
        <div className="todo-item">
          <span className="item-name">{this.props.item}</span>
          <span className="item-delete" onClick={this.DeleteItem}>X</span>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

when I click the X, I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined". How the hell can I fix this problem and actually succeed in deleting the object?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code.

1. class definition

Either use a class component

```js
class TodoItem extends React.Component {
}
```

or a function component

```js
const TodoItem = ({...}) => {
 return (
   <li>
    ...
   </li>
 )
}
```

Function components have to be written differently and there is no `this` object. So maybe stay with class components first

2. DeleteItem method

Common sense is to use small chars in the beginning so `deleteItem` but this is not a problem. Standard methods are not bound to this, so you have to do it manually

```js
 <span className="item-delete" onClick={this.DeleteItem.bind(this)}>X</span>
```

The better and imho easier solution is to use an arrow function, which  will be autobound.

```js
  DeleteItem = () => {
    console.log(this); //trying to log the item outputs undefined
    this.props.onDelete(this.props.item);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not binding `this.onDelete` and `this.DeleteItem` inside constructor. You can do `this.onDelete = this.onDelete.bind(this);` and `this.DeleteItem = this.DeleteItem.bind(this);` for your respective 2 component. Please refer the following code

```
var El2 = class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    //constructor
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos: ["work out", "eat breakfast", "take a shower"]
    };
    this.onDelete = this.onDelete.bind(this);
  }

  /**********methods**********/

  onDelete(item) {
    console.log(item, this.state.todos);
    let updatedTodos = this.state.todos.filter((val, index) => {
      return item !== val;
    });
    this.setState({ todos: updatedTodos });
  }

  /********rendering method*******/

  render() {
    let todos = this.state.todos;
    todos = todos.map((item, index) => {
      return <TodoItem item={item} key={index} onDelete={this.onDelete} />;
    });

    return (
      //works kinda like a main function
      <div id="todo-list">
        <p>the busiest people have the most leisure...</p>
        <ul>{todos}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  } //component rendering
}
```

```
var TodoItem = class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.DeleteItem = this.DeleteItem.bind(this);
  }

  DeleteItem() {
    console.log(this.props); //trying to log the item outputs undefined
    this.props.onDelete(this.props.item);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <li>
        <div className="todo-item">
          <span className="item-name">{this.props.item}</span>
          <span className="item-delete" onClick={this.DeleteItem}>
            X
          </span>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need check mmore information about porps and components 
https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

I also recommend not creating classes like that.
Today, react is recommending to make function components.

Like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App(){

const [todos, setTodos] = useState("");           ** hooks to create state**

 useEffect(() => {
                                        ** acess life cicle 
  }, [todos])                           **in this array is variable react obrseve to update**

----heres come your functions ------

return(
   <div id="todo-list"> 
    <p>the busiest people have the most leisure...</p>
    <ul>{todos}</ul>
  </div>
){

 }
}
´´´´
See in documentation about hook in link 
<https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html> 
has an example similar to what you are trying to do. 
I went a little far in explaining it but I believe it is useful.

I hope I helped.
```